# How to debug an AIR app in different iOS devices on iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, ios-simulator, flash-builder

I am developing application using Flash Builder 4.7, Flex 4.13 and AIR 16.0.

I want to debug my app on different iOS devices. iPhone5, iPhone 6, iPad, etc.

The iOS Simulator always starts up in iPhone 5.
If I try to change the device from the simulator menu "Hardware->Device-> iPad2" the application is stopped, the new device is loaded,
however when I debug the application, iPhone 5 is started again.

Could you please give me some insight how to debug on different devices?

Answer (score 1):

You are able to set default simulator in Terminal.app

```
launchctl setenv AIR_IOS_SIMULATOR_DEVICE "iPad"
launchctl setenv AIR_IOS_SIMULATOR_DEVICE "iPad Retina"
```

it worked for me but in other IDE - IntelliJ IDEA
but i think it should work for you too

to see current device you can use

```
launchctl getenv AIR_IOS_SIMULATOR_DEVICE
```

You may need to restart IDE and Simulator after device change

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how do you switch with the "hardware" menu (please enlighten me) but generally you can set up the device to be simulated in the Debug configurations menu - click on the small arrow to the right of the debug icon (red arrow) and select "Debug configurations". Make sure your application is selected on the left size (in my case it's "Test") and select the device to simulate on the right side (Select iOS as target platform and choose a device in the Device dropdown). Add more devices by clicking the "Configure" button.

[image]

Comment: In your example you use AIR Simulator. My question is addressing iOS Simulator which comes with xCode.